# Is 'Is that so?' perfect here?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

> A: Really? You like the Lakers? Actually I happen to have two tickets
> for tonight's game.
>
> B: Is that so?
>
> A: Yeah, would you like to go with me?

Hi. Would "is that so?" be perfect here? In the context B knows that A knows he likes the Lakers and that the extra ticket was meant for him all along.

Comment: It's fine. It is an idiom.

Comment: I would love to know why you ask. Are you writing a play?